# void function pointer return value in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, void

I was playing around with function pointers in C just to learn. I tried calling a void function and setting its result to an int.

```
void function(int x, int y){
printf("%d,%d\n",x,y);
}

int main(){
    int (*fptr)(int,int);
    fptr = function;
    int a = fptr(2,3);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get from this is:

`2,3
4`

After playing around with this a little, I realized that main is printing the number of characters in the printf statement in function(). Why is this happening? Is this expected output?

Comment: You should up your compiler's warning level: http://ideone.com/3DQN40

Comment: There's no "expected output" on undefined behavior.

Comment: I used gcc -Wall which indeed gave me a warning, but I'm curious why this behavior occurs

Comment: UB ! look about undefined behaviour on this site or on google.

Comment: You could get anything. Random. It might just happen to provide the return of the `printf` since that's what's left in the accumulator when the function returns (`printf` was the last thing called and it does have a return value). But it's not guaranteed. You can't count on it. So is it expected? No. Is it explainable? Yes.

Comment: See what `a` is before and after the call.  Probably the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is undefined behavior, and therefore, any behavior at all is "in spec", including ["Nasal Demons"](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

However, we can explain why this is *likely* happening on many modern platforms.

The return value of the last function that *has* a return value is usually placed in the **AX** register of the CPU.

`printf` was the last function that had a return value, and put `4` into the **AX** register.
Nothing else over-wrote the **AX** register in the meantime, and variable `a` gets the "return value" (even though `fptr` does not have a return value!), by getting the contents of the **AX** register, which is still `4`.

Comment: TIL printf returns a value.

Comment: I can't understand why there is **4** in the **AX** register. Is that a case or it can be recreate by others?

Comment: @neo_blackcap:  `printf` has a return value.  `printf` is documented that *"On success, the total number of characters written is returned."*.  So it returns that it printed 4 characters successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected result!
The `printf()` function will return the number of characters printed.In this case,`fptr(2,3)` will print `2,3` **AND** `\n`, therefor it return `4`